# Why is this precision rectifier circuit not producing a perfect output?

Tags: rectifier, precision-rectifier, ne5532

Can someone explain to me why this precision rectifier circuit isn't fully rectifying the signal? It seems to work well until the crest of the non-inverted sine wave signal. I've been trying to understand it but the only thing I can think of is that it might be the breakdown voltage of the diodes? That said, it doesn't seems like voltage would be the issue here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U3 output can't get close enough to the negative rail

try increasing the supply voltage (you can go to +/-15V on this part) or reducing the input signal amplitude.

The data sheet wants you to keep the output voltage at-least 2V away from the supply rails for best performance, and with only a 9V supply this circuit looks to be going less than 0.5V from the negative rail on U3 output when the input is +8V.